# Probability with integral of the CDF without learning it

Tags: probability

Given that you buy 135 calculators. 20% of them have a life time of more than 20 hours. And their life-time is distributed with Poisson.

> Find $\lambda$ )the Expectancy life time of a calculator)

What I thought is that $P(X>20) = 0.2$ but, $P(X>20)$ is the integral $\int_{20}^{\infty} \text{poisson PMF}$ and it is using the Gamma function which we haven't studied yet! So is there a better way of doing it? ($\Gamma$)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the second sentence means.  $65\%$ of $135$ is $87.75$.   Is that the exact quote from the problem statement?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, it doesnt make sense to me too, it means the question is broken?

Comment: @StackOMeow In my opinion, yes.

Comment: @callculus Ok, So I will fabricate the data of the question so it will make sense, I just want to get the idea of solving it , thank you guys.

Comment: The phrasing itself is a little bit messy as well. Btw, isnt´t the expected value of a poisson distributed variable just $\lambda$ and not $1/ \lambda$?

Comment: @callculus I think you are correct, I will fix it too

Comment: It should say something like "the probability that at least $65\%$ of the calculators last at least $20$ hours is $80\%$  We can't calculate $\lambda$ from knowing how many lasted.  We could have been very lucky or very unlucky.

Comment: @saulspatz the question is phrased like this I changed the data, is it still impossible?

Comment: I don't see how there's enough information to solve the problem.  As I said before, we might have been lucky or unlucky.  You ought to ask your instructor to clarify the question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what was meant is that the lifetime has an exponential distribution. In a "Poisson process," the number of "arrivals" in any given time period is a discrete random variable that has a Poisson distribution, and the time until the next "arrival" is a continuous random variable that has an exponential distribution.

An exponential distribution with expected value $\mu$ is $e^{-t/\mu} \left( \frac{dt} \mu \right) \text{ for } t>0.$ If a random variable (capital) $T$ has this distribution, then it is not hard to show that $\Pr(T>t) = e^{-t/\mu} \text{ for }t\ge0.$

(Note that I distinguish carefully between the capital $T$ and the lower-case $t$.)

So you have
\begin{align}
& 0.2 = \Pr(T>20) = e^{-20/\mu} \\[8pt]
& \ln 0.2 = \frac{-20}\mu \\[8pt]
& \mu = \frac{-20}{\ln0.2} \approx 12.4267
\end{align}